# R: How to give a named label to a number on a scale on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to relabel 0 and 1 on the y axis (See picture 1). When I do it with the "scale_y_discrete" function, it seems to shift the scale (See picture 2 and 3 below)?

Thankful for any advice.

```
Drucker2 <- function(z) {
  library(ggplot2)  
  name1 <- deparse(substitute(z))
  filename <- sprintf("Plot%s.png", gsub(" ", "_Alt", name1))
  p<-(ggplot() + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = z) +
        stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
        stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
        labs(title = name1) +
        ylab (name1)+
##following coding line makes the difference between the two pictures
        scale_y_discrete(name1, limits=c("0"="Not chosen", "1"="Chosen")) +
        scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))+
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1)
  )

  ggsave(filename,p, width = 5, height = 5)
}

Leader = x$Leader

Drucker2(Leader)
```

Image 1: Y Scale goes from 0 to 1
[image: Image 1: Y Scale goes from 0 to 1]

Image 2: The scale is like shifted not chosen = 0 ist above the graph
[image: Image 2: The scale is like shifted not chosen = 0 ist above the graph]

Image 3: Enlarging the Y scale  from "0, 1" to "0,2" reveals, that the scale is like shifted
[image]

Comment: Please make reproducible and minmal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation that the "not chosen" / "chosen" is added above is right - the y values are numeric (on a continuous scale) and < 1 - ggplot seems to "read" discrete scale values as 1, 2,..., therefore they appear above your charts. Either you need to convert the y values into a discrete values or, what I'd suggest you use annotations to show "chosen" vs. "not chosen" - here's a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Posture = rep(c("Closed", "Open"), 2),
         Sex = c("female", "male", "male", "female"),
         z = c(0.23, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4))

ggplot(df) + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = z) +
        stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
        stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0.2) +
        annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.21, label = "Chosen", hjust = 0) +
        annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.19, label = "Not Chosen", hjust = 0) +
         scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician",
            labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))
```

This is example is quick & dirty - especially the `x = 0.5, y = 0.21` in the annotations will not behave well when your scales are changing.

Comment: is right! I relabeled the data (0->1 & 1->2) and it worked. ggplot2 wants to be smooth and easy all the time, but it's rotten to the core. Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks for reply - ggplot may appear a bit odd at first sight and the learning curve is quite a bumpy road, but meanwhile I quite like it - because it's very powerful and - maybe even due to the underlying grammer-of-graphics-concept - you get a better understanding of your data.